# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds pandas and yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

I'm working with yfinance and pandas to get prices of stocks. I keep getting single positional indexer is out-of-bounds whenever the api can't get the data for a stock.

I'm trying to check if any of the index in the pandas series column is empty.

```
def checkPriceAction():
        global toStr
        for x in ticks:
            toStr = str(x)
            syb = yf.Ticker(toStr)
            data = pd.DataFrame(syb.history(interval="1m",period='1d'))
            data2 = pd.DataFrame(syb.history(interval="1m",period='1d', end=pastTime, start=pastTime2))
            data1 = data['Open'].reset_index(drop=True)
            dataPrev = data2['Open'].reset_index(drop=True)
            prev1 = data1.tail().iloc[2]
            prev2 = dataPrev.tail().iloc[2]
            if prev2 or prev1  == 0:
              pass
            if prev2 > prev1:     
                print(toStr, prev1, " : ", prev2 )
                print(toStr, 'Watch stop', aware)
            else:
                print(toStr, 'Proceed to buy with robinhood', aware)
```

I was expecting to not loop over the indices which are empty.

This is the result i get

AMD 58.564998626708984  :  59.30550003051758
AMD Watch stop 20:01:22.100031
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Last Hokage\Documents\Automated-ST-trading\stocks.py", line 90, in 
checkPriceAction() * time.sleep(300) * 3
File "C:\Users\Last Hokage\Documents\Automated-ST-trading\stocks.py", line 77, in checkPriceAction
prev2 = dataPrev.tail().iloc[2]
File "C:\Users\Last Hokage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1074, in **getitem**
return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
File "C:\Users\Last Hokage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1626, in _getitem_axis
self._validate_integer(key, axis)
File "C:\Users\Last Hokage\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1558, in _validate_integer
raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
PS C:\Users\Last Hokage\Documents\Automated-ST-trading>

Comment: Please include an example and reproducible code or we wont be able to help. As a suggestion: check if your API returns data.

Comment: The api returns the prices of stocks. Now whenever the api does'nt return the price is any stocks during runtime it raises and indexerror, im trying to catch that error and check for it so it does'nt stop my code from running. The code which im trying to modify is above